# How to go back to previous screen while using react native error boundary?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using error boundary in react native and after it encounters an error and shows fallback UI, I want to go back to previous screen by pressing a back button using react native navigation. How to achieve this?

this is my fall back ui:

```
import {
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import GoBack from '../../../../../../libs/common/src/lib/Assets/Images/Findings/chevron-left.svg';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const ErrorFallback = ({ error, resetError, navigation }) => {
    
    console.log('-----', navigation)
    return (
        <View style={{ margin: 20, marginTop: 20 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                <GoBack height={30} width={20} style={{ backgroundColor: "black", color: 'black' }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginTop: 10, color: 'red' }}>Error occurred:</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{error.message}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default ErrorFallback;
```

currently I can't go back to previous screen on using back button because console.log(navigation) is showing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **useNavigation** as

```js
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

and Remove the navigation prop from the **ErrorFallback** component declaration

try now after changing this